# OpenVPN client to client - Allow only certain profiles to be able to connect to other clients

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have alot of raspberry pi clients connecting to an openVPN server - they are currently all setup to talk to each other.
This is done via client-to-client

They all have static IP addresses and will range from 10.8.0.2 to 10.8.255.255

I want to be able to have a config file somewhere stating that only certain ip addresses are allowed to access another client.

This possible via iptables or rules ?

Comment: to be able to use iptables for this, you must remove the client-to-client option, or iptables will never see packets to filter.

Comment: Any idea on how to set this up

Comment: here's  a Q/A from SF explaining: [OpenVPN client-to-client](https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client)